# Matrix, Array and Index in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix, indexing

I would like to manage matrix and array to build an output file.
This is the scenario:

- I have a matrix Index_Matrix = Matrix[[0,3,6,7,8,11],[5,12,19,-1,-1,-1]];
- An Array Result_Array = Array.new(1000,"-1"); The array is fulfill by data

I would like to use the value of matrix as index for my array. Then put the corresponding Array value into a string. Like this (pseudocode):

```
for i in 0 to 100
    for j in 0 to 100
        string = Array[Index_Matrix[i][j]]
        File.open(yourfile, 'w') { |file| file.write(string) }
    end
end
```

I'm not able to use the matrix value as index for my array.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept is correct. The error is in options to `File.open`. It should be 'a' to append content instead of write.

```
ii.times { |i|
  jj.times { |j| 
    File.open('yourfile', 'a') { |file| file.write(ar[ma[i,j]])}
  }
}
```

And also be aware that calling `ar[-1]` will return last array element. Hope that's what you want.